# ASP.Net User Control not working when added at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

1. I have simply created a user control in asp.net which has a textbox,calendar and a button.

   1. On the click event of that button i am making the calendar visible,and on the calendar's `onselectionchanged` event i am passing the selected date to the textbox.
   2. Now i have a .aspx page in which i am adding this user control at RUN TIME.
   3. The user control gets added,but the click event of the button by which i am making the calendar visible is not getting fired.

What is the Issue? Its working fine when i add that user control at design time.
But when i add it at run time in not working.

<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Dates.ascx.cs" Inherits="Date"%>

```
//created a public object named 'users' of control class
public partial class View_now : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public Control users;  
}

//loaded the user control in page load event
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    users = LoadControl("~\\Dates.ascx");
}


//applied the user control to a panel
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel2.Controls.Add(users);
}
```

Now when i click the usercontrol's button,the click event doesn't fire.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? Use the Page_Init() event instead?

Comment: yes i did but it didnt worked. :(

Answer (score 1):

Add the controls during Page_Init() not Page_Load(). That should do the trick.

Comment: @mathewtinus, can you update your question with the code where you're trying to load your control?